# How can i use step for both optional and value in parameters in cucumber

Tags: cucumber

**Can anyone help me out. It should for both scenarios mentioned below when we pass parameters or empty.**

```
Given User is on login screen

When User performs login with existing user account that has players in the account with <username> and <password>

  | username          | password|
  | testing@gmail.com | invalid |
  | testing@gmail.com |         |
```

Steps

```
@When("^User performs login with existing user account that has players in the account with (.+) and (.+)$")
    public void user_performs_login_with_existing_user_user_account_that_has_players_in_the_account(String username,String password) throws Throwable {
        try {           
                loginScreenCoreLogic.performLogin(username, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ErrorReporter.reportError(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Posted an answer please accept if it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using right cucumber expressions.

`.*` is greedy, meaning that it will ignore the next delimiter of your regex until it itself is not fulfilled, unless the regex following `.*` is against the end of the target string.

**Feature**:

```
@Regression
  Scenario Outline: Test scenario
    Given User is on login screen
    Then verify the message "File Upload Successful." in create a consent or do not call or wrong number file page

Examples: 
  | username          | password |
  | testing@gmail.com | invalid  |
  | testing@gmail.com |          |
```

**Stepdefinition**:

```
@When("User performs login with existing user account that has players in the account with (.*) and (.*)$")
public void test(String username,String password) {      
           System.out.println("Output: "+username +","+ password);
}
```

**Output**:

```
Output: testing@gmail.com,invalid
Output: testing@gmail.com,
```